# forms.FilePathField doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm very new to django and python. I'm trying to display the list of files in a folder on my system using FilePathField like this below but for some reason, no files are displayed. I tried in many different ways but nothing worked. All I need is to get the name of the file selected. Can somebody please help me?

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField()
    file = forms.FilePathField(path='C:\input')
```

Here is my views.py

```
def post_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        # A POST request: Handle Form Upload
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 


    return render(request, 'polls/post_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: silly question. I printed the BASE_DIR path from settings.py and used the same path here and it worked.

Comment: It may have something to do with the backslash in your input path - you either need to escape it with another backslash (`"C:\\input"`) or use a regular slash (`"c:/input"`).